# Purpose of Immutable or Unmodifiable Collections

Tags: java, collections, guava

What are the real benefits of Immutable or Unmodifiable collections, or objects?

As programmers, we try to write code without bugs, such that a user cannot break the system, and that bad actors cannot hack into it. To me, Immutable objects seem to try to prevent **programmers** from making silly mistakes.

Is there more to it than that?

Comment: Yes; that is exactly the point. Programmers make mistakes all the time.

Comment: Collections and simple objects alike: one does not need to make copies for additional usage, can simply share the object reference, concurrency is immediately possible (without costing mechanisms). You can put the object as key in Set or Map without bothering that the object is altered so set/map gets corrupted (total subtrees/buckets becoming inaccessible). Think what a mutable String would be.

Comment: You'll learn more about the concept from this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object and from reading [Effective Java](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-3rd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0134685997/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable classes and collections really help to avoid concurrency issues with multiple threads trying to modify the same objects.